# ASP.NET Core Identity: Difference between [Authorize] and user null check?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Why does the Identity scaffold use user null checks `if(user==null)` if there is the `[Authorize]` annotation for the Authorization middleware? Are the null checks safer than Authorize?

```
var user = _userManager.GetUser(User);
if(user == null)
{
   return NotFound("User not found");
}
```

```
[Authorize]
public class TestModel : PageModel
{
}
```

Doesn't authorize take much less work to write?

Comment: Could it be that you aren't distinguishing between Authentication and Authorization? Authorization in the common case does not need a User. You can Authorize calls by other means. A user is needed if you want to do something in the context of a user not neccessarily for authorization.

Comment: From what I've learned authorize checks for users. It can also check for claims, roles, and more, but by default, it checks for an existing user.

Comment: You implement it for reusability of the code. What if you later decide to use that code for some public pages that don't use authorization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User is never `null` if code passes `[Authorize]`.
Some people wrongfully do it as they are used to it before this type of authenticating was a thing.